# Tabhost and fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-pageradapter

I am unable to understand properly what these functions are used for in my `FragmentActivity` class.

```
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            position = pos;
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(pos);

            new Getquestions().execute();
        }



        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}
```

I am using a view pager for page sliding, and what I want to do is, if a condition is false, for example I have three `edit texts` in `fragment one`, and if a user wants to slide to `fragment two` without filling up the texts then the must not slide.

I tried to find any such example but I am unable to find it. Can anyone help? Understanding these functions will help me implement my thing I guess

Answer (score 0):

Documented advantage of fragments, is that they can be added or removed to the activity on a run-time.

What you want is have a single fragment initially, and once the requirements are fulfilled - add a next fragment to your activity.

Comment: no actually i wish to have multiple fragments initially, but i want to restrict the user to initial fragment unless he completes all the fields.

Comment: @HassaanRabbani So you want a fragment to be there, but scrolling to it disabled? I afraid in that case you have to implement your own animation classes. That is way too inefficient

Answer (score 0):

I have got an answer from another forum

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

```
private boolean isPagingEnabled;

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.isPagingEnabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.isPagingEnabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.isPagingEnabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
    this.isPagingEnabled = b;
}
```

}

Now when you want to disable swiping just setPagingEnable = false;

and in the layout file replace any `<com.android.support.V4.ViewPager>` tags with `<com.yourpackage.CustomViewPager> tags`.